# how to form a better boolean in an Android Java Method

Tags: java, android, methods, boolean

I've got this method  that gets called multiple times in a day.

```
public void dayUpdater() {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat numDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

    String[] Days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    String day = numDate.format(now);

    if (day.equals(Days[0])) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 5000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[1])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 5000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[2])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 4000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[3])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 3000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[4])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 2000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[5])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 1000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (day.equals(Days[6])) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 1000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Now only 1 "if-statement" gets called each day. I've created a bool called xbool to help call my method once a day. Also the method to be called is the one below.

```
private boolean xbool = true;

private void reStartDay() {
    saveAllContents();
    clearAllEntries();
}
```

If xbool is false we call our method then turn it to true. and when it's true we do nothing. here's working example to be applied to every if-statement.

```
if (day.equals(Days[0])) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 5000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (xbool == false) {
            reStartDay();
            xbool = true;
        }
    }
```

My issue is once the next day comes. i.e. another if statement is valid in this case from the code above to:

```
if (day.equals(Days[1])) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + numDate.format(now)
                + " is " + 5000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (xbool == false) {
            reStartDay();
            xbool = true;
        }
    }
```

Where day is now equal to Days[1] instead of Days[0]. Problem is my xbool is true. So there won't be a call to "reStartDay()" on this new day because xbool isn't false.
What I've decided to do is switch every if statement in **dayUpdater** to the opposite. Which looks like so :

```
if (day.equals(Days[0])) { 
    if (xbool == false){
        reStartDay();
        xbool = true;
    }
}
if (day.equals(Days[2])) { 
    if (xbool == true){
        reStartDay();
        xbool = false;
    }
}
```

Wednesday checks for false and turns xbool to true. etc etc.. u get the pattern.

Once i get to Sunday though it does not align to suit Monday's expectations, Sunday Checks if xbool is false and changes it to true.

But Monday expects xbool to be false so it can call reStartDay() for Monday.
I need Suggestions on what to do. or what to change. pls
I've never been good with boolean so i know i'll learn something no matter the answer/suggestion I get.

Comment: Beyond that: every time when you have an array or list, and you start to manually put down indexes like this ... you are doing something wrong. The *basic* theme is to *iterate* such structures in a loop, and to avoid using them the way you did. You see, you could as well have written `String day1 =  ... ; String day2 = ... ` ... your code doesn't gain anything from using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your code, it looks like you want to execute certain code only once per day despite the method running multiple times a day.

To achieve same, you can do this.

Declare an instance variable like this,

```
private String currentDay = null;
```

In your dayUpdater method, instead of writing so many ifs, what if you just write it like this,

```
public void dayUpdater() {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat numDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String[] Days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    String day = numDate.format(now);
    if (!day.equals(currentDay)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total for " + day
                + " is " + 5000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        reStartDay();
        currentDay = day;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You can get rid of that String[] Days = {"Monday"... declaration as well